Subordinate adverbial clauses


There was silence as the leader spoke.
As the leader spoke, there was silence.




He is honest though he is poor.
Though he is poor, he is honest.




He is large-hearted though he is not rich.
Though he is not rich, he is large-hearted.


Here these subordinate clauses are modifying what?
The main verbs or the adjectives?
Though these sentences are simple, these sentences are confusing me.

They all modify the main clause of the sentence, not just a single word.

The term "simple" has specific meaning in the context of sentences: A simple sentence contains only one independent clause (a subject and a predicate) and expresses a single complete thought. So none of your examples are "simple" sentences, since they all contain subordinate (dependent) clauses as well as a main clause.

Sometimes adverbs and adverbial phrases can modify a single word as in this example "He quickly ate".
--------------------------|
|                  --------------
|                  |            |
Subject He    adv quickly    verb ate

This isn't always the case. In your examples the adverbial is not modifying a word, but is a phrase at the top level of the sentence.
              |------------------------------ 
    ------------------                      |
    |                |                      |   
conj As  clause (the leader spoke),   clause (there was silence)

The adverbial (which could be at the before or after the main clause "there was silence") doesn't modify a particular word in the sentence.
If you are confused,  try constructing a tree.
